# Why won't SQL round correctly from my batch script?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file, rounding

I'm at a loss here. I'm trying to take a centisecond variable from a batch script and pull that variable into a sql table using sqlcmd. That part workds great. The part that is screwing with my head is that I'm trying to convert the variable from centiseconds into minutes.

I know that batch is all but unable to handle float math so I thought I'd be sneaky and work around that so that I could have minutes to the nearest tenth place in my sql table. I left the math in centiseconds in the batch file and decided to convert in my sqlcmd external query like so:

```
sqlcmd -S <SERVER> -d <DATABASE> -v Var1="%variable1%" Var2="%variable2%" 
Var3="%variable3%" Var4="%variable4%" -i "\\path\to\the\query.sql"
```

The query looks like this where Var3 is the variable I'm converting.

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ($(Var1), $(Var2), ROUND(($(Var3)/6000),2), $(Var4))
```

however, when I look at the entry in the sql table it hasn't been changed at all by the round function. No matter whether my arguement is 1, 2, 3, etc... it stays rounded to the nearest integer value.

So is there something that I'm missing? Shouldn't the `Var3` value be able to be converted to a float value inside of the query and then dumped in?

Comment: Try explicitly casting. Something like: `ROUND(CAST(($Var3) AS float)/6000),2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Operator `/` is type-specific](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx), so you should cast your integer to the float, like this:

```
ROUND(CAST(($Var3) AS float) / 6000), 2)
```

or use the division by float, like this:

```
ROUND(($Var3 / 6000.0), 2)
```

> > Returns the data type of the argument with the higher precedence.
> >     For more information, see [Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I just figured this out and came to say that exact one. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `Var3` is an int - dividing an int by an int results in an int. An easy fix would be to change `6000` to `6000.0`.